# To remove more than predictors in lm() function in r

Tags: r, multiple-regression, linear-model

I've 10 predictors and 1 response variable.
I tried running linear model using

```
lm(y~., data=mydata)
```

If I just need to remove one predictor 'age', I can write

```
lm(y~.-age, data=mydata)
```

If the summary of the model suggest that more than one variables are not significantly contributing to the model. How can I efficiently write a code for linear model removing these variables.

I tried

```
lm(y.-c(age, weight), data=mydata)
```

But I got the error

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ . - c(age, weight),  : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'c(age, weight)')
```

Please help.

Comment: Software-related questions are off-topic on this site so I'm voting to close this thread. As a hint, you can always use `lm(mpg~.-cyl-disp-hp, mtcars)` or `lm(mpg~., mtcars[,-c(5:10)])`.

Comment: No problem :) You can always take a tour https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour to learn more about the site ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can chain several predictors with a minus sign

```
lm(y ~ . - age - weight, data=mydata)
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have tried it before asking. I was trying to use a vector of variables instead.

Answer (score 0):

Following are some of the methods which can be used :

1. Subset selection : Identifies subset of predictors that are related to the response. This can be accomplished using best subset selection or stepwise subset selection methods.
2. Shrinkage methods : Coefficients of predictors weakly related to response are shrunken towards zero. Ridge and Lasso regression can be used for this.
3. Dimension reduction : Find the predictors which are linearly correlated to other predictors. Can be done using PCA (Principal component analysis).

For more details and worked out examples in R you can refer to chapter 6 from "Introduction to Statistical Learning", which can be downloaded for free from here -> http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/

Comment: I am already following the same book. And recently read about these methods. But here I am concerned about how to write a code for removing selected variables from the model.